# Is there a way to define the starting tab in the navigation advanced sample?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-architecture-navigation, android-components

I am working on the project [NavigationAdvancedSample](https://github.com/android/architecture-components-samples/tree/master/NavigationAdvancedSample) of the 
[architecture-components-samples](https://github.com/android/architecture-components-samples) repository. This project shows a workaround to support multiple back stacks for each tab of a [BottomNavigationView](https://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/material/bottomnavigation/BottomNavigationView?hl=en).

In this configuration, you define a navigation graph for each of your tabs and let the class extension [NavigationExtensions](https://github.com/android/architecture-components-samples/blob/master/NavigationAdvancedSample/app/src/main/java/com/example/android/navigationadvancedsample/NavigationExtensions.kt) handle the different back stacks for you. Everything works fine, but I can't find a way to select the starting tab of the `BottomNavigationView`. I have tried to tweak the `NavigationExtensions` but without success.

By default, the selected tab on the application startup is the first of the bottom navigation view. How can I change this behavior in order to show the second or third tab for example?

Answer (score 0):

Changing order of items in the **navGraphIds** and selecting item in **bottomNavigationView** helped me.

```
private fun setupBottomNavigationBar() {
    val bottomNavigationView = findViewById<BottomNavigationView>(R.id.bottom_nav)
    val navGraphIds = listOf(R.navigation.list, R.navigation.home, R.navigation.form)
    bottomNavigationView.selectedItemId = R.id.list
    // Setup the bottom navigation view with a list of navigation graphs
    val controller = bottomNavigationView.setupWithNavController(
        navGraphIds = navGraphIds,
        fragmentManager = supportFragmentManager,
        containerId = R.id.nav_host_container,
        intent = intent
    )
    // Whenever the selected controller changes, setup the action bar.
    controller.observe(this, Observer { navController ->
        setupActionBarWithNavController(navController)
    })
    currentNavController = controller
}
```

As a result I have **R.id.list** item as first.